# How to use trully multiline commentaries in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

For instance, this won't work:

```
puts "hello"

"""

var1 = 123
var2 = "#{var3}"  # exception!

"""
```

This will throw an exception in runtime, even though the code is supposed to be skipped as a commentary.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Sigil `~S`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#sigil_S/2) that prevents string interpolation:

```
~S"""

var1 = 123
var2 = "#{var3}"  # exception!

"""
```

By default, Elixir tries to interpolate all binaries, including comments.